# Canvas method TouchUp not picking up my touches

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have been struggling with this for three days now because I thought something was wrong with my **App Inventor** code, because nothing would happen on touch and then the app would just crash. But it seems app (the `TouchUp` method specifically) is not recognizing my touches. I tried looking for this on Google and App Inventor forums but can't find any posts of this sort.

It does recognize my touch with `TouchDown` method but then it doesn't automatically call the `TouchUp` when the drag/swipe is over. I do need this specific method because I want to know the direction in which the user swiped.

The weird part is that this same code worked previously but after changing some other parts, it stopped working and I have no idea why this could have happened.

I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: please be more specific and paste some code

Comment: It would really help if you provided a screenshot of your **relevant blocks**, so we can see what you are trying to do, and where the problem may be.

Comment: I would if I would know how to change it so it would be more readable and still relevant. The part which seems to be causing a problem (like it loops forever or something) is made of more than 100 blocks, calling 9 other functions and not in English. Even if I did change all the names and variables I doubt anyone would read all the code :/

Comment: prepare a small test project as small as possible and test your `TouchUp` event there and if this still does not work, then provide a screenshot of that test project